# How to retrieve column values by column name in python whit cx_Oracle

Tags: python, oracle10g

I'm programming a script that connects to an Oracle database and get the results into a log file. I want to get a output like this:

> FEC_INCLUSION = 2005-08-31 11:43:48,DEBITO_PENDIENTE = None,CAN_CUOTAS = 1.75e-05,COD_CUENTA = 67084,INT_TOTAL = None,CAN_CUOTAS_ANTERIOR = None,COD_INVERSION = 1,FEC_MODIFICACION = 10/04/2012 09:45:22,SAL_TOT_ANTERIOR = None,CUOTA_COMISION = None,FEC_ULT_CALCULO = None,MODIFICADO_POR = CTAPELA,SAL_TOTAL = 0.15,COD_TIPSALDO = 1,MONTO_COMISION = None,COD_EMPRESA = 1,SAL_INFORMATIVO = None,COD_OBJETIVO = 5,SAL_RESERVA = None,INCLUIDO_POR = PVOROPE,APORTE_PROM = 0.0,COSTO_PROM = None,CREDITO_PENDIENTE = None,SAL_PROM = 0.0,
>
> FEC_INCLUSION = 2005-08-31 11:43:49,DEBITO_PENDIENTE = None,CAN_CUOTAS = 0.0,COD_CUENTA = 67086,INT_TOTAL = None,CAN_CUOTAS_ANTERIOR = None,COD_INVERSION = 9,FEC_MODIFICACION = 25/02/2011 04:38:52,SAL_TOT_ANTERIOR = None,CUOTA_COMISION = None,FEC_ULT_CALCULO = None,MODIFICADO_POR = OPEJAMO,SAL_TOTAL = 0.0,COD_TIPSALDO = 1,MONTO_COMISION = None,COD_EMPRESA = 1,SAL_INFORMATIVO = None,COD_OBJETIVO = 5,SAL_RESERVA = None,INCLUIDO_POR = PVOROPE,APORTE_PROM = 0.0,COSTO_PROM = None,CREDITO_PENDIENTE = None,SAL_PROM = 0.0,

I created a dictionary with the query results:

```
def DictFactory(description,data):
    column_names = [col[0] for col in description]
    results = []
    for row in data:
        results.append(dict(zip(column_names,row)))
    return results
```

Then I created this function which finally save the results into my log:

```
def WriteLog(log_file,header,data):
    file_exist = os.path.isfile(log_file)
    log = open(log_file,'a')
    if not file_exist:
        print "File does not exist, writing new log file"
        open(log_file,'w').close()

    mydata = DictFactory(header,data)
    checkpoint_name = ReadCheckpointName()
    string = ''
    for m in mydata:
        for k,v in m.items():
            string = string + k + ' = ' + str(v) + ','
            if k == checkpoint_name:
                #print "KEY FOUND"
                cur_checkpoint = v
                cur_checkpoint = str(cur_checkpoint)
        #print string
        string = string + '\n'
    print cur_checkpoint
    log.write(string + '\n')
    WriteCheckpoint(cur_checkpoint,checkpoint_file)
    log.close()
```

This is the main function:

```
def GetInfo():
    mypool = PoolToDB()
    con = mypool.acquire()
    cursor = con.cursor()
    GetLastCheckpoint()
    sql = ReadQuery()
    #print sql
    cursor.execute(sql)
    data = cursor.fetchall()
    WriteLog(log_file,cursor.description,data)
    #WriteCsvLog(log_file,cursor.description,data)
    cursor.close()
```

But I realized that it works if I use a query that fetch few records, however if I try to fetch many records my script never ends.

This is my output when I executed a query with 5000 records. As you can see it takes too long.

```
jballesteros@SplunkPorvenir FO_TIPSALDOS_X_CUENTA]$ python db_execution.py
Starting connection: 5636
GetLastCheckpoint function took 0.073 ms
GetLastCheckpoint function took 0.025 ms
ReadQuery function took 0.084 ms
File does not exist, writing new log file
DictFactory function took 23.050 ms
ReadCheckpointName function took 0.079 ms
WriteCheckpoint function took 0.204 ms
WriteLog function took 45112.133 ms
GetInfo function took 46193.033 ms
```

I'm pretty sure you know a much better way to do what I am trying to do.

This is the complete code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# encoding: utf-8

import re
import sys
try:
    import cx_Oracle
except:
    print "Error: Oracle module required to run this plugin."
    sys.exit(0)

import datetime
import re
import commands
import os
from optparse import OptionParser
import csv
import time

#################################
####   Database Variables    ####
#################################
Config = {
            "host"     : "",
            "user"     : "",
            "password" : "",
            "instance" : "",
            "port"     : "",
            }

Query = {
            "sql"                   : "",
            "checkpoint_datetype"   : "",
            "checkpoint_name"            : "",
            }

dir = '/home/jballesteros/PENS2000/FO_TIPSALDOS_X_CUENTA/'
connection_dir = '/home/jballesteros/PENS2000/Connection'
checkpoint_file = dir + 'checkpoint.conf'
log_file = '/var/log/Pens2000/FO_TIPSALDOS_X_CUENTA.csv'
internal_log = '/var/log/Pens2000/internal.log'
query = dir + 'query'

sys.path.append(os.path.abspath(connection_dir))
from db_connect_pool import *

def Timing(f):
    def wrap(*args):
        time1 = time.time()
        ret = f(*args)
        time2 = time.time()
        print "%s function took %0.3f ms" % (f.func_name,(time2-   time1)*1000.0)
        return ret
    return wrap

@Timing
def InternalLogWriter(message):
    now = datetime.datetime.now()
    log = open(internal_log, 'a')
    log.write("%s ==> %s" % (now.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"),message))

    log.close()
    return

@Timing
def GetLastCheckpoint():
    global cur_checkpoint
    conf = open(checkpoint_file, 'r')
    cur_checkpoint = conf.readline()
    cur_checkpoint = cur_checkpoint.rstrip('\n')
    cur_checkpoint = cur_checkpoint.rstrip('\r')
    conf.close()

@Timing
def ReadQuery():
    global cur_checkpoint
    GetLastCheckpoint()
    qr = open(query, 'r')
    line = qr.readline()
    line = line.rstrip('\n')
    line = line.rstrip('\r')
    Query["sql"], Query["checkpoint_datetype"],Query["checkpoint_name"] = line.split(";")
    sql = Query["sql"]
    checkpoint_datetype = Query["checkpoint_datetype"]
    checkpoint_name = Query["checkpoint_name"]

    if (checkpoint_datetype == "DATETIME"):
        sql = sql + " AND " + checkpoint_name + " >= " +     "TO_DATE('%s','YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') ORDER BY %s" %   (cur_checkpoint,checkpoint_name)
    if (checkpoint_datetype == "NUMBER"):
        sql = sql + " AND " + checkpoint_name + " > " + "%s ORDER BY   %s" % (cur_checkpoint,checkpoint_name)

    qr.close()
    return str(sql)

@Timing
def ReadCheckpointName():
    qr = open(query, 'r')
    line = qr.readline()
    line = line.rstrip('\n')
    line = line.rstrip('\r')
    Query["sql"], Query["checkpoint_datetype"],Query["checkpoint_name"] = line.split(";")
    checkpoint_name = Query["checkpoint_name"]
    return str(checkpoint_name)

@Timing
def LocateCheckPoint(description):
    description
    checkpoint_name = ReadCheckpointName()
    #print checkpoint_name
    #print description
    startcounter = 0
    finalcounter = 0
    flag = 0
    for d in description:
        prog = re.compile(checkpoint_name)
        result = prog.match(d[0])
        startcounter = startcounter + 1
    if result:
        finalcounter = startcounter - 1
        counterstr = str(finalcounter)
        print "Checkpoint found in the array position number: " + counterstr
        flag = 1
    if (flag == 0):
        print "Checkpoint did not found"
    return finalcounter

@Timing
def DictFactory(description,data):
    column_names = [col[0] for col in description]
    results = []
    for row in data:
        results.append(dict(zip(column_names,row)))
    return results

@Timing
def WriteCsvLog(log_file,header,data):
    checkpoint_index = LocateCheckPoint(header)
    file_exists = os.path.isfile(log_file)
    with open(log_file,'ab') as csv_file:
        headers = [i[0] for i in header]
        csv_writer = csv.writer(csv_file,delimiter='|')

        if not file_exists:
            print "File does not exist, writing new CSV file"
            csv_writer.writerow(headers) # Writing headers once
    
        for d in data:
            csv_writer.writerow(d)
            cur_checkpoint = d[checkpoint_index]
            cur_checkpoint = str(cur_checkpoint)

    WriteCheckpoint(cur_checkpoint,checkpoint_file)
    csv_file.close()

@Timing
def WriteLog(log_file,header,data):
    file_exist = os.path.isfile(log_file)
    log = open(log_file,'a') 
    if not file_exist:
        print "File does not exist, writing new log file"
        open(log_file,'w').close()

    mydata = DictFactory(header,data)
    checkpoint_name = ReadCheckpointName()
    #prin #string = ''
    for m in mydata:
        for k,v in m.items():
            string = string + k + ' = ' + str(v) + ','
            if k == checkpoint_name:
                #print "KEY FOUND"
                cur_checkpoint = v
                cur_checkpoint = str(cur_checkpoint)
        #print string
        string = string + '\n'
    print cur_checkpoint
    log.write(string + '\n')
    WriteCheckpoint(cur_checkpoint,checkpoint_file)
    log.close()

@Timing
def WriteCheckpoint(cur_checkpoint,conf_file):
    conf = open(conf_file,'w')
    conf.write(cur_checkpoint)
    conf.close()

@Timing
def GetInfo():
    mypool = PoolToDB()
    con = mypool.acquire()
    cursor = con.cursor()
    GetLastCheckpoint()
    sql = ReadQuery()
    #print sql
    cursor.execute(sql)
    #data = cursor.fetchall()
    #WriteLog(log_file,cursor.description,data)
    #WriteCsvLog(log_file,cursor.description,data)
    cursor.close()

def __main__():
    parser = OptionParser()
    parser.add_option("-c","--change-   password",dest="pass_to_change",help="Change the password for database    connection",metavar="1")
    (options, args) = parser.parse_args()

    if (options.pass_to_change):
        UpdatePassword()
    else:
        GetInfo()

__main__()
```

This is a query sample:

> SELECT COD_EMPRESA, COD_TIPSALDO, COD_INVERSION, COD_CUENTA,     COD_OBJETIVO, CAN_CUOTAS, SAL_TOTAL, INT_TOTAL, SAL_RESERVA, APORTE_PROM, SAL_PROM, COSTO_PROM, SAL_TOT_ANTERIOR, FEC_ULT_CALCULO, INCLUIDO_POR,    FEC_INCLUSION, MODIFICADO_POR, TO_CHAR(FEC_MODIFICACION,'DD/MM/YYYY    HH24:MI:SS') AS FEC_MODIFICACION, CUOTA_COMISION, MONTO_COMISION,    SAL_INFORMATIVO, CREDITO_PENDIENTE, DEBITO_PENDIENTE, CAN_CUOTAS_ANTERIOR FROM FO.FO_TIPSALDOS_X_CUENTA WHERE ROWNUM <=100000 AND FEC_INCLUSION >= TO_DATE('2005-08-31 11:43:49','YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') ORDER BY FEC_INCLUSION

PS: I've really been searching in google and this forum about my question but I haven't found anything similar.

Comment: It would help to know what you are querying (an example query) and the table(s) you are accessing (an example table). Also, any reason for using `cursor.fetchall` rather than letting the cx_oracle library manage the cursor and loop through the data until the data has been read?

Comment: Hello Beege, thanks a lot for your reply. I edited the post and I attached all my code and a sample query. There is not reason for using `cursor.fetchall`, it just the way I know and I always do. If there is a better way to do it I will happy to receive a documentation about it :).